# Syntax for transposing rows and columns in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio

This is the original gridview. The headings are in the top most row with data for each item in the following rows:

```
ProId      ProdName      Price      Stock
1          P1            1000       10
2          P2            2000       20
3          P3            5000       25
```

I want to transpose my grid-view, so I can have all headings in the first, leftmost column and all details for an item are in a column instead of a row.

```
ProId        1       2        3
ProdName     P1      P2       P3
Price        1000    2000     5000
Stock        10      20       25
```

Here is the code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="JobPostingId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" AllowPaging="True">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="JobPostingId" HeaderText="JobPostingId" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="JobPostingId" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-lg"></HeaderStyle>

            <ItemStyle CssClass="visible-lg"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="JobId" HeaderText="JobId" SortExpression="JobId" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-lg"></HeaderStyle>

            <ItemStyle CssClass="visible-lg"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ApplicantName" HeaderText="ApplicantName" SortExpression="ApplicantName" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-lg"></HeaderStyle>

            <ItemStyle CssClass="visible-lg"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ApplicantContactNo" HeaderText="ApplicantContactNo" SortExpression="ApplicantContactNo" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-lg"></HeaderStyle>

            <ItemStyle CssClass="visible-lg"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-lg"></HeaderStyle>

            <ItemStyle CssClass="visible-lg"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StateId" HeaderText="StateId" SortExpression="StateId" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-lg"></HeaderStyle>

            <ItemStyle CssClass="visible-lg"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CountryId" HeaderText="CountryId" SortExpression="CountryId" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-lg"></HeaderStyle>

            <ItemStyle CssClass="visible-lg"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CreationDate" HeaderText="CreationDate" SortExpression="CreationDate" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-lg"></HeaderStyle>

            <ItemStyle CssClass="visible-lg"></ItemStyle>

        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="View More" CommandName="viewApplication" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="black" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="black" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HRJobPortalConnectionString4 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [JobPortalJobPosting]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: which language was the table generated with? and can you post the code that generates the table?

Comment: The Code is written over C#.I have added the code also.

Comment: Don't think you can use GridView to achieve that. You need a DetailView. But I don't use asp.net since razor came along. Can't help you there. FYI this is not a JavaScript related question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CSS for this purpose. But before...
Use `ListView` instead of `GridView`. `ListView` allows to render HTML as you want, not only as `table`. So

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvRows" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder" DataSourceID="sqlProds">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div class="my-tbl">
            <div class="my-row">
                <div>prod id</div>
                <div>name</div>
                <div>price</div>
            </div>
            <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></div>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="my-row">
            <div><%#Eval("productid") %></div>
            <div><%#Eval("productname") %></div>
            <div><%#Eval("unitprice","{0:c}") %></div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlProds" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindCnn %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT top 4 productid,productname,unitprice FROM dbo.products"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This produces following HTML:

```
<div class="my-tbl">
    <div class="my-row">
        <div>prod id</div>
        <div>name</div>
        <div>price</div>
    </div>

     <div class="my-row">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>Chai</div>
        <div>$18.00</div>
    </div>

     <div class="my-row">
        <div>2</div>
        <div>Chang</div>
        <div>$19.00</div>
    </div>

     <div class="my-row">
        <div>3</div>
        <div>Aniseed Syrup</div>
        <div>$10.00</div>
    </div>

     <div class="my-row">
        <div>4</div>
        <div>Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning</div>
        <div>$22.00</div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

And now use CSS for rows layout

```
    .my-tbl{display:flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-direction: column;}
    .my-row{display:flex;
            flex-direction:row;}
    .my-tbl>div>div{width:90px;
                    overflow:hidden;
                    white-space:nowrap;}
```

And for column layout:

```
    .my-tbl{display:flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-direction: row;}
    .my-row{display:flex;
            flex-direction:column;}
    .my-tbl>div>div{width:90px;
                    overflow:hidden;
                    white-space:nowrap;}
```